# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null - error on one test phone but not the other

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm writing an android app that is designed for multiple phones to be able to interface with a google sheet at the same time. but I'm getting this error on one of my test phones:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Process: com.example.frcscout22sheets, PID: 9729
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
    at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:84)
    at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:69)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzl.getToken(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base@@18.0.4:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base@@18.0.4:3)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:267)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:292)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:880)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:525)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:576)
    at com.example.frcscout22sheets.Data$onCreateView$2$1.invokeSuspend(Data.kt:55)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@afbaf4, Dispatchers.Default]
```

this error only occurs on one of my test phones. More specifically, the second one I tested it on. The original one works just fine.

This is the code that throws the error:

```
package com.example.frcscout22sheets

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ClearValuesRequest
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class Data : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_data) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false)
        val matchNumber = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Match_Number)
        val teamNumber = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Team_Number)
        val autoPoints = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Auto_Points)
        val teleopPoints = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Teleop_Points)
        val endgamePoints = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Endgame_Points)

        val clear = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        clear.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            matchNumber.setText("")
            teamNumber.setText("")
            autoPoints.setText("")
            teleopPoints.setText("")
            endgamePoints.setText("")
        })

        val send = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        send.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                if (isFull()) {
                    var row = 0
                    MainActivity.service.spreadsheets()
                    while (true) {
                        row++
                        println(MainActivity.ID)
                        if (MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().get(MainActivity.ID, "A$row").execute().getValues()[0][0] == "end") {
                            MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().append(MainActivity.ID, "A${row+1}", ValueRange().setValues(listOf(listOf("end")))).setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute()
                            MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().clear(MainActivity.ID, "A${row}", ClearValuesRequest()).execute()
                            println(row)
                            break
                        }
                    }

                    MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().append(MainActivity.ID, "A$row", ValueRange().setValues(listOf(listOf(matchNumber.text.toString())))).setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute()
                    MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().append(MainActivity.ID, "B$row", ValueRange().setValues(listOf(listOf(teamNumber.text.toString())))).setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute()
                    MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().append(MainActivity.ID, "C$row", ValueRange().setValues(listOf(listOf(autoPoints.text.toString())))).setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute()
                    MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().append(MainActivity.ID, "D$row", ValueRange().setValues(listOf(listOf(teleopPoints.text.toString())))).setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute()
                    MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().append(MainActivity.ID, "E$row", ValueRange().setValues(listOf(listOf(endgamePoints.text.toString())))).setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute()
                }
            }
        })
        return view
    }

    private fun isFull() : Boolean {
        if (view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Match_Number)?.text.toString() == "") {
            return false
        }
        if (view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Team_Number)?.text.toString() == "") {
            return false
        }
        if (view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Auto_Points)?.text.toString() == "") {
            return false
        }
        if (view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Teleop_Points)?.text.toString() == "") {
            return false
        }
        if (view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Endgame_Points)?.text.toString() == "") {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

this line specifically:

```
if (MainActivity.service.spreadsheets().values().get(MainActivity.ID, "A$row").execute().getValues()[0][0] == "end") {
```

I login to my google account to get the credentials for the google sheet api inside the mainactivity:

```
package com.example.frcscout22sheets

import Home
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.frcscout22sheets.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var isLoggedIn = false

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_SIGN_IN = 1
        lateinit var service : Sheets
        lateinit var ID : String
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val dataFragment = Data()
        val allianceSelectionFragment = AllianceSelection()
        val homeFragment = Home()

        setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)

        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            requestSignIn(baseContext)
        }

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.data -> setCurrentFragment(dataFragment)
                R.id.alliance_selection -> setCurrentFragment(allianceSelectionFragment)
                R.id.home -> setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment)
            commit()
        }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { account ->
                        val scopes = listOf(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS)
                        val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(baseContext, scopes)
                        credential.selectedAccount = account.account

                        val jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
                        val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
                        val sheet = Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                            .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .build()
                        getSheet(sheet)
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestSignIn(context: Context) {
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Scope(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
            .build()
        val client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions)

        startActivityForResult(client.signInIntent, REQUEST_SIGN_IN)
    }

    private fun getSheet(sheets: Sheets) : Sheets {
        service = sheets
        println(service)
        return sheets
    }

}
```

I logged in to the account that was working on the original device on the new device and I got the same error.

why might this be happening? What can I do to fix it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the problem.

1. The Google Sheet needed to be made editable by all those with the link
2. I changed to following:

```
private fun requestSignIn(context: Context) {
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Scope(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
            .build()
        val client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions)

        startActivityForResult(client.signInIntent, REQUEST_SIGN_IN)
    }
```

to

```
private fun requestSignIn(context: Context) {
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Scope(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        val client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions)

        startActivityForResult(client.signInIntent, REQUEST_SIGN_IN)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting GoogleAuthException when updating spreadsheet values.
GoogleAuthException is caused when the client is invalid.
And because of that the **name** parameter in android.accounts.Account class is **null**.
I suggest that you check the google account on both of your test phones (the working one and not working one) and see if you can find any discrepancies.

Comment: So I'm using different accounts on the phones. Will that cause a problem if I only have one oauth2 credential in the Google cloud console?

Comment: When you say the client is invalid, do you mean the spreadsheet or the phone accessing the spreadsheet? @REX